# Regex on JSON body - Sibling

Tags: javascript, json, regex

How would I target the value in `123` using regex based on the id value `code-2` and only within the `fields` property?

```
{
  "name": "Tom",
  "fields": [
     {
        "id": "code-1",
        "value": "abc",
        "message": "hi"
     },
     {
        "id": "code-2",
        "value": "123",
        "message": "bye"
     },
     {
        "id": "code-3",
        "value": "abc",
        "message": "goodnight"
     }
  ],
  "other": "Jerry"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse JSON with JS the natural way and access what you need.

```js
var json = `{
  "name": "Tom",
  "fields": [
     {
        "id": "code-1",
        "value": "abc",
        "message": "hi"
     },
     {
        "id": "code-2",
        "value": "123",
        "message": "bye"
     },
     {
        "id": "code-3",
        "value": "abc",
        "message": "goodnight"
     }
  ],
  "other": "Jerry"
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.fields[1].id);
```

Comment: That is not the question. For example, "How do I make pasta from scratch" - Answer: "Just buy pasta premade from a restaurant"

Comment: @wsyq1n This is pasta from scratch though. You're just not aware that you asked "How do I make pasta from a hammer?"

Comment: Umm.. the point still stands: "How do I make pasta from a hammer?" Answer "Restaurant"

Comment: @wsyq1n You'll have to do a better job of explaining why you wish to make pasta from a hammer (regex) instead of using the pasta ingredients (`JSON.parse()`) which are literally in front of you and readily available.

Comment: The existence of the third party api that I'm working with which is looking for a regex pattern is not needed to ask the question.